# Can I turn off a condition in a Tableau filter?

Tags: filtering, tableau-api

I have a carrier list for which we're disqualifying carriers who have done more than 90% of deliveries for one customer. So I have a custom field built for that. However, if I just apply a parameter to filter out 0 in column 5, it is only going to filter out those CUSTOMERS that are at 90 + percent of deliveries. However, I need to filter out CARRIERS who meet that condition with any one customer. See image1 below. Carrier 1MTX LLC would still show up in the view, even if I filter out the 0. Thus the conditional filter on carrier name that you see pictured in image below.

[image: Extract]

I need to be able to allow a user to turn this condition off or on, based on what view is needed. Some users will want to be able to see all carriers, regardless of whether or not they've met qualification guidelines, while others will just want to see qualified carriers.  Any ideas on how I could toggle the actual condition of the filter on or off? I can't share my workbook.

[image: Carrier filter]

I ended up doing this. I created a column which I will hide in the view that partitions by carrier and customer, restarting at each carrier, that displays the MAX value of Customer % of Volume. Then I created a True/False filter so that users can filter on the hidden column.

[image]

Comment: Its Ok that you don't want to share your workbook.  However, please include at least the structure of your data.  If you could add some sample fake data to replicate your problem on that data, It'll help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I was making this a lot harder than it needed to be. I ended up just creating a table calculation on the Customer % of Volume Field (which I will hide in the view) that displays MAX(Customer % of Volume), partitioned by carrier and customer. Then I created a True/False filter for users. That way, they can filter on the hidden column.

Thank you for the replies though.

Answer (score 0):

If you could please provide more details of your workbook in terms of structure suggested by Anil - that would allow us to provide more information.

However, you are on the right path and paramters is the way to go as opposed to conditional filtering in the logic you have shown.

The problem with that is it persists and reduces your dyanmic approach of filtering for different user views.

Having said that please see some of the following links which might help you - I would suggest creating corresponding calculated fields with a parameter to give you dynamic flexibility.

**Link 1:** [Basic use of parameters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/changing-views-using-parameters.htm)

**Link 2:** [Parameter based on selection criteria](https://data-flair.training/blogs/tableau-parameter-tutorial/)

**Link 3:** [Dynamic Parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa2VlsLk98k) & [Advanced Parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AOu07obs7E)

Unfortunatly without more information on your workbook - I can only suggest resources.

Hope these resolve your issue.

Comment: I added what I could from the workbook, but I think that the question was pretty clear from the get-go. See the edit above. I created a calculated field for a qualification flag that returns 1 if the % of deliveries for a customer is <=.9, otherwise it returns 0. That is column 6. I can't just filter on column 6 though. As you can see, that would leave the carrier called 1MTX LLC on the view, even though it is not qualified.

Comment: @BrianMinturn try using Exclude. I understand now what you a trying to do. There is a sample workbook attached here and works to exclude subset of info you are trying to replicate with carriers. Link (https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6WFoSAN/exclude-value-based-on-parameter-selection)

Comment: I actually ended up having to go in a different direction. I first tried to get total deliveries by carrier, by carrier sales rep and by customer/carrier with partitions in my SQL, but kept hitting a wall. So I just created a table calculation in Tableau, partitioned on carrier and customer, to display MAX(Customer % of Volume) - (see edit above).

Answer (score 0):

Use this field as filter

```
{Fixed [CARRIER_NM] : MAX([CUSTOMER QUALIFICATION FG])} =0
```

I presume that `customer qualification fg` field is numeric one, else it needs to convert to numeric in aforementioned calculation

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Sure! Let me know whether it served the purpose.